# Password strength checking with Regex - How to pass 1st validation but not the 2nd in included example?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, passwords

What string could I use to enter in the first code test below but fail the 2nd test?

```
 public static bool ValidatePassword(string password)
    {
        const string symbolsDisallowed = "<>";
        if (password.Length < 8) return false;
        var categories = new[] { @"\d", "[A-Z]", "[a-z]", @"[^\dA-Za-z" + symbolsDisallowed + "]" };
        var matchCount = categories.Count(c => Regex.IsMatch(password, c));
        return matchCount >= 3 && !Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[" + symbolsDisallowed + "]");
    }
```

2nd

```
        public static bool ValidatePasswordStrength(string password)
    {
        if (password.Length < 8) return false;
        var categories = new[] { @"\d", "[A-Z]", "[a-z]", @"[!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;-]" };
        var matchCount = categories.Count(c => Regex.IsMatch(password, c));
        return matchCount >= 3;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Why the downvote? Looks like a pretty clear question to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `AAAaaa++`.

The `+` is allowed (1st test) but not included in the "special symbols" category in the 2nd test.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh..ok..

- ~aa4~~~~
- ^^AA4^^~
- ~ 4g~ ~ ~
- ()~4F[][]
- (())|aaa

Comment: Yes, whatever is not in `!@#$%&\/=?_.,:;-` and is not `<` or `>` is ok.